# PHP: Can somebody simplify this IF statement for me?

Tags: php

```
if($object_type == 'regular') {
    if($u_login == $object_user || $u_access >= 3 || $object_access >= 4) {
        echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
        echo '<p><span class="r_button"><a href="/delete_link/'.$object_key.'?link_id=2">'.ex_lang('str_btn_delete').'</a></span></p>';
    }
} else
if($object_type == 'comment') {
    if($u_login == $object_user || $u_access >= 2 || $object_access >= 4) {
        echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
        echo '<p><span class="r_button"><a href="/delete_link/'.$object_key.'?link_id=2">'.ex_lang('str_btn_delete').'</a></span></p>';
    }
}
```

So the thing that if object is different type user need to have diff access level. How this statement can be simplified for don't having duplicates in it?

---

I generally forgot about groups in if's, thank you for reminding me it!

```
if($u_login == $object_user || $object_access >= 4 || ($object_type == 'regular' && $u_access >= 3) || ($object_type == 'comment' && $u_access >= 2)) {
    echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
    echo '<p><span class="r_button"><a href="/delete_link/'.$object_key.'?link_id=2">'.ex_lang('str_btn_delete').'</a></span></p>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both conditions check for `$u_login == $object_user` and `$object_access >= 4`, with only the `$object_type` and `$u_access` differing. As such, you can bring these two checks up a level, and check against `$object_type` and `$u_access >= 3` inside the outer condition.

As such, the statement can be re-written like this, shrinking one line of code:

```
if($u_login == $object_user || $object_access >= 4) {
    if($object_type == 'regular' && $u_access >= 3) {
        echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
        echo '<p><span class="r_button"><a href="/delete_link/'.$object_key.'?link_id=2">'.ex_lang('str_btn_delete').'</a></span></p>';
    }
    else if($object_type == 'comment' && $u_access >= 2) {
        echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
        echo '<p><span class="r_button"><a href="/delete_link/'.$object_key.'?link_id=2">'.ex_lang('str_btn_delete').'</a></span></p>';
    }
}
```

Although depending on your definition of 'simplify', you could also cut out the outer conditional entirely by making use of some brackets:

```
if(($u_login == $object_user || $object_access >= 4) && ($object_type == 'regular' && $u_access >= 3)) {
    echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
    echo '<p><span class="r_button"><a href="/delete_link/'.$object_key.'?link_id=2">'.ex_lang('str_btn_delete').'</a></span></p>';
}
else if(($u_login == $object_user || $object_access >= 4) && ($object_type == 'comment' && $u_access >= 2)) {
    echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
    echo '<p><span class="r_button"><a href="/delete_link/'.$object_key.'?link_id=2">'.ex_lang('str_btn_delete').'</a></span></p>';
}
```

However, it's worth nothing that both of your conditionals currently do the exact same thing, so the code could even be simplified to:

```
echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
echo '<p><span class="r_button"><a href="/delete_link/'.$object_key.'?link_id=2">'.ex_lang('str_btn_delete').'</a></span></p>';
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It's not working if `$u_login != $object_user` and `$object_access <= 3`. Echo should be activated even if just one of `$u_access` things is true.

UPD: Wait, I will test the other code you provided.

Comment: @DIES -- Your question itself doesn't provide a use case to cover such a situation; your existing code will not cover that. You could always just change the two conditions to say `|| $u_access` instead of `|| $u_access >= 3`, which would solve that problem :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Your inner conditions are slightly off. You need to use `&&` rather than `||` in order to preserve logic.

Comment: @B.Fleming -- There are `||` inside of the two brackets. The `&&` joins the bracketed components together, which essentially 'steps into' the two original `if` conditions. You need `((A OR B)  AND (C OR D))` unless I am misunderstanding the question :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I was referring to the original refactor at the top, where you have nested if statements. The nested ones need the replacing. That being said, in the second refactor I think you might need `((A OR B) && (C && D))`. Nested if statements act like a "pseudo-AND", which is being ignored for the cases of C and D which were originally nested.

Comment: @B.Fleming -- Ahh, now I see. Yes, a slight oversight on my part. I've updated my answer to correct that :)

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the best place to ask for help refactoring your code, but what the heck. Notice that you have two conditions that are exactly the same and being checked in both if conditions. Why not pull those up to the root level?

```
if($u_login == $object_user || $object_access >= 4) {
    if($object_type == 'regular' && $u_access >= 3) {
        echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
        echo '<p><span class="r_button"><a href="/delete_link/'.$object_key.'?link_id=2">'.ex_lang('str_btn_delete').'</a></span></p>';
    }

    if($object_type == 'comment' && $u_access >= 2) {
        echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
        echo '<p><span class="r_button"><a href="/delete_link/'.$object_key.'?link_id=2">'.ex_lang('str_btn_delete').'</a></span></p>';
    }
}
```

Notice that we don't need an `else` anywhere in here because the conditions provided are, by nature, mutually exclusive. This can make readability a bit simpler.